# Using C# 6 with WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, c#-6.0

I would like to use interpolated strings in this old WCF project, and I have tried to change the target framework to .NET Framework 4.8 (from project pages). But this does not seem to change the C# version from 5 to 6.

I'm still getting the error

`Feature 'interpolated strings' is not available in C# 5. Please use language version 6 or greater.`

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 4):

You have to update [language version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version) in your .csproj file,

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <LangVersion>6</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

When you use language version as a **6**, compiler accepts only syntax that *is included in C# 6.0 or lower*.

If you want to use any features which are included in higher or the latest version of C# like *[pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching), [switch expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression), [global using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-10#global-using-directives)* then you can use **`<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>`** instead of **`<LangVersion>6</LangVersion>`**.

More details, kindly check [C# language version reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version#c-language-version-reference)

---

**Demo to update .csproj file:**

[image]

Comment: But there is no csproj file for the WCF - it's all in the SLN file it seems.

Comment: go to file explorer and navigate to WCF project folder, there you will find `.csproj` file

Comment: The sln file contains no reference to a csproj file. There is no csproj file anywhere to be seen.

Comment: @OlaEldøy is this a "web site" folder thing?

Comment: @OlaEldøy, I added .gif file which demonstrate editing of `.csproj` file. Hope this will help you

Answer (score 2):

edit the csproj: `<LangVersion>6</LangVersion>` (or higher); done

Comment: But there is no csproj file for the WCF - it's all in the SLN file it seems.

Comment: @OlaEldøy WCF doesn't "have" or "not have" a csproj; that's unrelated; are you perhaps talking about a legacy "web site" folder-based pseudo-project thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can also and a `LangVersion` environment variable.

You can use https://aks.as/msbuildlog to debug your build.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can also try to download the nuget package.
[`Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform/).

> Replacement CodeDOM providers that use the new .NET Compiler Platform
> ("Roslyn") compiler as a service APIs. This provides support for new
> language features in systems using CodeDOM (e.g. ASP.NET runtime
> compilation) as well as improving the compilation performance of these
> systems.